# GitLab issue on mac with Android Studio : SSL peer handshake failed with GitLab repo

Tags: android, git, android-studio, gitlab

Suddenly started getting this error during fetch/push/pull from GitLab repo using Android Studio. Tried to run commands from terminal as well no success.

I am using Android studio. **Gitlab** integration was working fine from many month suddenly started getting this error:

unable to access : SSL peer handshake failed, the server most likely requires a client certificate to connect.

Config global setting for http already set to false. Was not facing any issue it's been months taking pull/push suddenly started getting this error.

Am using mac os : 10.12.6. Am not able to push/pull/fetch from my GitLab repo.

Please help.

Comment: Please help. Am struck unable to fetch/push/pull.

Comment: Did u find a solution?I am facing the same problem

Comment: @Sonika Yes. I don't remember exactly but I think please use Go->Home option there is .gitconfig file delete it  or any other file with git in name. You may copy it somewhere else to be on safer side & then delete.